# Javascript performing function if control + s are depressed

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

I am new to javascript and want to know how to call a function if <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> are depressed on my webpage. So far I have come up with this :

```
<% 


document.body.onclick = function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey){
        document.body.onclick = function(f){
            if(f.keyCode = 115){}
                menubar.saveAction();
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode = 115){
        document.body.onclick = function(f){
            if(f.ctrlKey){}
                menubar.saveAction();
            }
        }
    }
} 
%>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depressed? :( A keypress is not a mouseclick. You need to listen to the keydown handler instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) { // 83 = s
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser action
        alert("ctrl + s"); // your code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: do note that that particular key combo is reserved by some browsers/OSs, though ch/win recently started allowing it...